# SP13 - Video is uploaded in Asset library programmatically, but preview image doesn't show up

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, video, ssom, asset-library

I want to upload video file in asset library with SSOM.

This is my code:

```
SPFolder newFolder = videoFilesLibEN.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add("Video");   
SPFile spfile = newFolder.Files.Add("VideoName.mp4", binaryArray, false);
```

Video uploaded, but preview image doest exist? Content type of asset library is set to video(default).

Where is a problem?

Comment: can you try different approach of uploading video in asset lib : reference -- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ab2bb36-2727-4305-bd9c-156ee5ff2094/how-to-add-videos-in-to-asset-library-programmatically-using-object-model?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious